# How code python/pyspark if statement (medium/hard complexity)?

Tags: loops, if-statement, join, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I'm working in Pyspark with two datasets and am stuck on how to code something. I'm sure this could involve if statements, various joins and/or groupBy() functions.

The two dataframes have information essentially like below. In practice the dfs are huge and with many instances of the example given.

df1:

| Name1 | Name2 | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Z | 1 |
| A | Y | 1 |
| B | X | 1 |
| B | W | 1 |
| C | V | 1 |

df2:

| Name1 | Name2 | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Z | 2 |
| B | U | 2 |

In df1, sometimes 'name1' will match to multiple 'name2'.

In df2, 'name1' is always unique (ie always one instance of each 'name1').

I would like:
if 'name1' matches to multiple 'name2' in df1, and one of those name1/name2 pairs is in df2 (ie A-Z row in the example), then drop all other rows in df1 with that name1 (ie drop A-Y row) (so B-X, B-W, C-V remain).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what about the "key" column ? is it there just to decorate ?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The key column is there to demonstrate that the rows in df1 and df2 are always different. Key never equals 1 in df2, and always equals 1 in df1.

Comment: so they're just useless .... they probably should not even be in your example ...

Comment: It would matter if a join was done, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably :

```py
df1_ = df1.groupBy("Name1").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("Name2")).alias("Names2"))
df2_ = df2.groupBy("Name1").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("Name2")).alias("Names2"))

df = df1_.join(df2_, how="left", on="Name1")


df.withColumn(
    "intersect", F.array_intersect(df1_["Names2"], df2_["Names2"])
).withColumn(
    "intersect",
    F.when(F.size(F.col("intersect")) > 0, F.col("intersect")).otherwise(
        df1_["Names2"]
    ),
).select(
    "Name1", F.explode("intersect").alias("Name2")
).show()

+-----+-----+                                                                   
|Name1|Name2|
+-----+-----+
|    B|    X|
|    B|    W|
|    C|    V|
|    A|    Z|
+-----+-----+
```